# Go exec.Command(...).Wait() hangs for ever

Tags: go

Hi guys for some reason Wait() when I execute mysql command hangs for ever, does anyone know why?
Here is my code.

```
// Import imports data into Local database
func (x MySQL) Import(data string, opt LocalDb) {
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command("mysql", x.importOptions(opt)...)
    // Set < pipe variable
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    errChk(err)

    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    cmd.Start()

    // Write data to pipe
    io.WriteString(stdin, data)
    fmt.Println("Importing " + x.DB + " to localhost...")

    // Log mysql error
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(stderr.String())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Importing complete")
    }
}
```

This function accomplishes everything and mysql imports the data into database but it never return from Wait() just freezes there even though is completed.

Comment: Does it still hang when you remove the line `cmd.Stderr = &stderr`?

Comment: mysql waits for more input.

Comment: if I remove cmd.Stderr it doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't closed the `stdin` pipe. MySQL will remain active until it is.

The fix is thus simple:

```
// Write data to pipe
io.WriteString(stdin, data)
stdin.Close()
fmt.Println("Importing " + x.DB + " to localhost...")
```

The fact that `StdinPipe()` acts in this way is documented as such:

> StdinPipe returns a pipe that will be connected to the command's standard input when the command starts. *The pipe will be closed automatically after Wait sees the command exit. A caller need only call Close to force the pipe to close sooner.* For example, if the command being run **will not exit until standard input is closed**, the caller must close the pipe.